# How to make SQL to a function

Tags: php

I am trying to make the following code to be a php variable. The idea is so I can get all the user data I need by giving the variable the id of the user.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $displayname = $row['user_displayname'];
  }
}
```

"display name" here is what I want to get.

It works when not in a function but it does not work in the function. 
Perhaps I am doing something wrong, here. is how I am doing it.

```
function get_userdetails($user_id) {

// Figure out displayname of rulechanger
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $displayname = $row['user_displayname'];
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need to call the function somewhere (after the declaration), like $usere_detail = get_userdetails(<the id>);

Comment: where did you declare the $conn variable/object?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `$conn` is a global variable (object) representing your database connection. In order to access it inside a function you need to use the `global` keyword - in this case `global $conn;`

You will need to do the same with `$displayname` if you intend to refer to it outside of the function (after the function has set its value). Probably best here will be to simply `return $displayname` from your function.